# mysql update between row and shift current to right

Tags: mysql

how to update column value of specific id and shift after to right.

```
id    track
 1      3
 2      5
 3      8
 4      9
```

want to update id 3 track column value to 10, result like this

```
id    track
 1      3
 2      5
 3      10
 4      8
 5      9
```

id column is auto_increment

or any suggestion it's my pleasure.

thank you.

Comment: You will mess up track 8 and 9 id's?

Comment: It is a pretty untypical use of IDs if your job is to shift all following data after inserting (in this case updating) a row. Are you sure you found the 'best' database design for this problem? It looks a little bit like you should reference your tables in a other way...

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid tweaking auto_increments. Auto increment keys are usually supposed to be used internally (e.g. for linking purposes). If you want to order tracks, i suggest you add a seperate numeric field "ordernro" to the table and update that

To add a column order nro to a table named album, do like this:

alter table album add ordernro int(2) after id;

Then copy the current value for id into this new column:
update album set ordernro=id;
(do this only once after adding the column)

To insert track 10 at position 3 first shift the rows:
update album set ordernro = ordernro + 1 where ordernro >= 3;

And then insert track 10:
insert into album (ordernro, track) values (3, 10);
Remember to update your existing insert/update/select statements accordingly.

The result can be checked by:

select * from album order by ordernro;
(The id will now be "mixed up", but that doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= x;
```

x being the id where you place your current track.

Comment: It should be `WHERE id >= x` (ie `>=` not just `>`) as you want to "free" the `x` but I agree with "tehvan" that messing with ID / auto_increment columns is not a good idea.

Comment: Ofcource, good catch. Messing with ai and id is by all means no good idea.

Comment: it work if id is not auto_increment. insert track 10 into id 3 after run your query. but I still need id to be auto_increment.

Comment: I think that the best you can do here is remove the auto increment functionality and select the TOP/MAX element or similar and increment it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [JK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286390/jk) 's answer is that MySQL returns error saying that is can't `UPDATE` because the index at `x+1` would be duplicate.

What I did is

```
UPDATE table SET id = id + 100 WHERE id >= x;
UPDATE table SET id = id - 99  WHERE id >= x;
```

And then `INSERT` my row at index `x`